# Xcode C++ Errors preventing further output past srand()

Tags: c++, xcode, random, time

I am working on a program that generates two random numbers and an if statement that generates either a "+" for addition or a "-" for subtraction. I currently cannot check and see what my putput is so I can correct any mistakes because the program runs my opening "Welcome" statement then displays in blue parentheses (lldb) and the code stops there. I noticed next to my srand(time(0)) function that it turned green and says "thread 1: breakpoint 1.1" and under it reads "Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'time_t' (aka 'long') to 'unsigned int'". Is there a way to workaround these or get the errors to go away? My code is below. Any help or insight would be appreciated, thanks!

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int main()

{
    cout << "Welcome to the Math Tutor!" << endl;

    int N1, N2;
    int O = rand() % 2;
    int Result;
    int Answer;

    srand(time(0));

    if(O == 2)
    {
        cout << "+";
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "-";
    }

    N1 = 100 + rand() % 999;
    N2 = 100 + rand() % 999;
    Result = N1 + O + N2;

    cout << setw(10) << N1 << endl;
    cout << setw(10) << N2 << O << "\n";
    cout << setw(10) << "------\n\n";

    cout << "Enter your answer: ";
    cin >> Answer;

    if(Answer == Result)
    {
        cout << "You are correct!\n\n";
    }

    else
    {
        cout << "You are incorrect, the correct answer is: " << Result << "\n\n";
    }

    cin.ignore(1);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Not related to your problem, but the value of `O` will always be the same, since you generate it, prior to initializing the random number generator. EDIT: your code seems to compile fine on [ideone](https://ideone.com/HB7EdK).

Comment: Please don't use 'O' as the name of a variable. It looks too much like '0'.

Answer (score 1):

`time(0)` returns a value of type `time_t`, which apparently is a `long` on your machine.

When you pass this `long` to `srand()`, expecting an `unsigned int`, not all values of a `long` will fit in an `unsigned int`. You can shoehorn it in by using a cast to tell the compiler that you don't care much about this.

```
srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(0)));
```

As you look for some, more or less, random numbers, the loss of precision is not important in this case.

Comment: Thank you Bo! This got rid of the error, but it brought me to another error. I now get one that starts at my if(O == 2) statement that reads thread 1: breakpoint 1.1